# Rearrange Columns in Multilevel Pivot Dataframe Python

Tags: python-3.x, pivot-table

I have a pivoted dataframe that looks like this:

[pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJvdj.png)

I want to rearrange the time columns, so I need it to be '9am','10am',....'5pm'.
The sorting function does not seem to work and always puts '9am' last. Is there a way to rearrange it?

This is the dataframe values I used for the pivot table:

```
{'Time': {360: '9am',
  361: '10am',
  362: '11am',
  363: '12pm',
  364: '1pm',
  365: '2pm',
  366: '3pm',
  367: '4pm',
  368: '5pm',
  369: '9am',
  370: '10am',
  371: '11am',
  372: '12pm',
  373: '1pm',
  374: '2pm',
  375: '3pm',
  376: '4pm',
  377: '5pm',
  378: '9am',
  379: '10am',
  380: '11am',
  381: '12pm',
  382: '1pm',
  383: '2pm',
  384: '3pm',
  385: '4pm',
  386: '5pm',
  387: '9am',
  388: '10am',
  389: '11am',
  390: '12pm',
  391: '1pm',
  392: '2pm',
  393: '3pm',
  394: '4pm',
  395: '5pm',
  396: '9am',
  397: '10am',
  398: '11am',
  399: '12pm',
  400: '1pm',
  401: '2pm',
  402: '3pm',
  403: '4pm',
  404: '5pm',
  405: '9am',
  406: '10am',
  407: '11am',
  408: '12pm',
  409: '1pm',
  410: '2pm',
  411: '3pm',
  412: '4pm',
  413: '5pm',
  414: '9am',
  415: '10am',
  416: '11am',
  417: '12pm',
  418: '1pm',
  419: '2pm',
  420: '3pm',
  421: '4pm',
  422: '5pm',
  423: '9am',
  424: '10am',
  425: '11am',
  426: '12pm',
  427: '1pm',
  428: '2pm',
  429: '3pm',
  430: '4pm',
  431: '5pm'},
 'Building': {360: '25 Copthall',
  361: '25 Copthall',
  362: '25 Copthall',
  363: '25 Copthall',
  364: '25 Copthall',
  365: '25 Copthall',
  366: '25 Copthall',
  367: '25 Copthall',
  368: '25 Copthall',
  369: '25 Copthall',
  370: '25 Copthall',
  371: '25 Copthall',
  372: '25 Copthall',
  373: '25 Copthall',
  374: '25 Copthall',
  375: '25 Copthall',
  376: '25 Copthall',
  377: '25 Copthall',
  378: '25 Copthall',
  379: '25 Copthall',
  380: '25 Copthall',
  381: '25 Copthall',
  382: '25 Copthall',
  383: '25 Copthall',
  384: '25 Copthall',
  385: '25 Copthall',
  386: '25 Copthall',
  387: '25 Copthall',
  388: '25 Copthall',
  389: '25 Copthall',
  390: '25 Copthall',
  391: '25 Copthall',
  392: '25 Copthall',
  393: '25 Copthall',
  394: '25 Copthall',
  395: '25 Copthall',
  396: '25 Copthall',
  397: '25 Copthall',
  398: '25 Copthall',
  399: '25 Copthall',
  400: '25 Copthall',
  401: '25 Copthall',
  402: '25 Copthall',
  403: '25 Copthall',
  404: '25 Copthall',
  405: '25 Copthall',
  406: '25 Copthall',
  407: '25 Copthall',
  408: '25 Copthall',
  409: '25 Copthall',
  410: '25 Copthall',
  411: '25 Copthall',
  412: '25 Copthall',
  413: '25 Copthall',
  414: '25 Copthall',
  415: '25 Copthall',
  416: '25 Copthall',
  417: '25 Copthall',
  418: '25 Copthall',
  419: '25 Copthall',
  420: '25 Copthall',
  421: '25 Copthall',
  422: '25 Copthall',
  423: '25 Copthall',
  424: '25 Copthall',
  425: '25 Copthall',
  426: '25 Copthall',
  427: '25 Copthall',
  428: '25 Copthall',
  429: '25 Copthall',
  430: '25 Copthall',
  431: '25 Copthall'},
 'Floor': {360: '2nd',
  361: '2nd',
  362: '2nd',
  363: '2nd',
  364: '2nd',
  365: '2nd',
  366: '2nd',
  367: '2nd',
  368: '2nd',
  369: '2nd',
  370: '2nd',
  371: '2nd',
  372: '2nd',
  373: '2nd',
  374: '2nd',
  375: '2nd',
  376: '2nd',
  377: '2nd',
  378: '2nd',
  379: '2nd',
  380: '2nd',
  381: '2nd',
  382: '2nd',
  383: '2nd',
  384: '2nd',
  385: '2nd',
  386: '2nd',
  387: '2nd',
  388: '2nd',
  389: '2nd',
  390: '2nd',
  391: '2nd',
  392: '2nd',
  393: '2nd',
  394: '2nd',
  395: '2nd',
  396: '2nd',
  397: '2nd',
  398: '2nd',
  399: '2nd',
  400: '2nd',
  401: '2nd',
  402: '2nd',
  403: '2nd',
  404: '2nd',
  405: '3rd',
  406: '3rd',
  407: '3rd',
  408: '3rd',
  409: '3rd',
  410: '3rd',
  411: '3rd',
  412: '3rd',
  413: '3rd',
  414: '3rd',
  415: '3rd',
  416: '3rd',
  417: '3rd',
  418: '3rd',
  419: '3rd',
  420: '3rd',
  421: '3rd',
  422: '3rd',
  423: '3rd',
  424: '3rd',
  425: '3rd',
  426: '3rd',
  427: '3rd',
  428: '3rd',
  429: '3rd',
  430: '3rd',
  431: '3rd'},
 'Type': {360: 'Breakout Space',
  361: 'Breakout Space',
  362: 'Breakout Space',
  363: 'Breakout Space',
  364: 'Breakout Space',
  365: 'Breakout Space',
  366: 'Breakout Space',
  367: 'Breakout Space',
  368: 'Breakout Space',
  369: 'Print Area',
  370: 'Print Area',
  371: 'Print Area',
  372: 'Print Area',
  373: 'Print Area',
  374: 'Print Area',
  375: 'Print Area',
  376: 'Print Area',
  377: 'Print Area',
  378: 'Coffee Counter',
  379: 'Coffee Counter',
  380: 'Coffee Counter',
  381: 'Coffee Counter',
  382: 'Coffee Counter',
  383: 'Coffee Counter',
  384: 'Coffee Counter',
  385: 'Coffee Counter',
  386: 'Coffee Counter',
  387: 'Kitchen Table',
  388: 'Kitchen Table',
  389: 'Kitchen Table',
  390: 'Kitchen Table',
  391: 'Kitchen Table',
  392: 'Kitchen Table',
  393: 'Kitchen Table',
  394: 'Kitchen Table',
  395: 'Kitchen Table',
  396: 'Meeting Room',
  397: 'Meeting Room',
  398: 'Meeting Room',
  399: 'Meeting Room',
  400: 'Meeting Room',
  401: 'Meeting Room',
  402: 'Meeting Room',
  403: 'Meeting Room',
  404: 'Meeting Room',
  405: 'Breakout Space',
  406: 'Breakout Space',
  407: 'Breakout Space',
  408: 'Breakout Space',
  409: 'Breakout Space',
  410: 'Breakout Space',
  411: 'Breakout Space',
  412: 'Breakout Space',
  413: 'Breakout Space',
  414: 'Print Area',
  415: 'Print Area',
  416: 'Print Area',
  417: 'Print Area',
  418: 'Print Area',
  419: 'Print Area',
  420: 'Print Area',
  421: 'Print Area',
  422: 'Print Area',
  423: 'Meeting Room',
  424: 'Meeting Room',
  425: 'Meeting Room',
  426: 'Meeting Room',
  427: 'Meeting Room',
  428: 'Meeting Room',
  429: 'Meeting Room',
  430: 'Meeting Room',
  431: 'Meeting Room'},
 'Avg': {360: 2,
  361: 3,
  362: 4,
  363: 5,
  364: 10,
  365: 7,
  366: 4,
  367: 3,
  368: 2,
  369: 0,
  370: 0,
  371: 0,
  372: 0,
  373: 0,
  374: 0,
  375: 0,
  376: 0,
  377: 0,
  378: 0,
  379: 0,
  380: 0,
  381: 1,
  382: 0,
  383: 0,
  384: 0,
  385: 0,
  386: 0,
  387: 0,
  388: 0,
  389: 0,
  390: 2,
  391: 1,
  392: 0,
  393: 0,
  394: 1,
  395: 0,
  396: 10,
  397: 14,
  398: 21,
  399: 13,
  400: 10,
  401: 15,
  402: 16,
  403: 12,
  404: 12,
  405: 1,
  406: 0,
  407: 2,
  408: 2,
  409: 3,
  410: 2,
  411: 2,
  412: 1,
  413: 0,
  414: 0,
  415: 0,
  416: 0,
  417: 0,
  418: 0,
  419: 0,
  420: 0,
  421: 0,
  422: 0,
  423: 5,
  424: 8,
  425: 8,
  426: 6,
  427: 6,
  428: 5,
  429: 6,
  430: 6,
  431: 4},
 'Max': {360: 4,
  361: 8,
  362: 8,
  363: 8,
  364: 15,
  365: 16,
  366: 10,
  367: 8,
  368: 6,
  369: 1,
  370: 2,
  371: 2,
  372: 1,
  373: 2,
  374: 1,
  375: 0,
  376: 0,
  377: 0,
  378: 0,
  379: 2,
  380: 3,
  381: 3,
  382: 2,
  383: 3,
  384: 0,
  385: 1,
  386: 0,
  387: 1,
  388: 2,
  389: 0,
  390: 3,
  391: 3,
  392: 1,
  393: 1,
  394: 1,
  395: 0,
  396: 19,
  397: 31,
  398: 28,
  399: 21,
  400: 19,
  401: 29,
  402: 21,
  403: 19,
  404: 18,
  405: 6,
  406: 3,
  407: 6,
  408: 4,
  409: 6,
  410: 4,
  411: 4,
  412: 3,
  413: 1,
  414: 0,
  415: 0,
  416: 1,
  417: 0,
  418: 1,
  419: 0,
  420: 0,
  421: 0,
  422: 0,
  423: 10,
  424: 13,
  425: 19,
  426: 16,
  427: 15,
  428: 12,
  429: 12,
  430: 15,
  431: 8}}
```

And this is the code I use to create the pivot table itself:

```
pivoted = df_popul_x_time.pivot(index=['Building','Floor','Type'], columns=['Time'], values=['Avg', 'Max'])\
            .reset_index()
pivoted.columns.name=None

pivoted = pivoted.swaplevel(0,1,axis = 1).sort_index(axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is to sort the first level of your multiindex columns. You can do this with `sort_index`, using your own function as `key`:

```
import re
def sort_time(time_str): # sort XXam / YYpm
    if not time_str:
        return ("a", 0) # the first columns ("") should stay at the beginning
    time, am_pm = re.split(r"(?<=\d)(?=\D)", time_str)
    return (am_pm, int(time) % 12)

def sort_col(ind):
    return pd.Index([sort_time(x) for x in ind])

pivoted = pivoted.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, key=sort_col)
print(pivoted)
```

Output:

```
Time                                    9am     10am     11am     12pm     1pm     2pm     3pm     4pm     5pm    
         Building Floor            Type Avg Max  Avg Max  Avg Max  Avg Max Avg Max Avg Max Avg Max Avg Max Avg Max
0     25 Copthall   2nd  Breakout Space   2   4    3   8    4   8    5   8  10  15   7  16   4  10   3   8   2   6
1     25 Copthall   2nd  Coffee Counter   0   0    0   2    0   3    1   3   0   2   0   3   0   0   0   1   0   0
2     25 Copthall   2nd   Kitchen Table   0   1    0   2    0   0    2   3   1   3   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
3     25 Copthall   2nd    Meeting Room  10  19   14  31   21  28   13  21  10  19  15  29  16  21  12  19  12  18
4     25 Copthall   2nd      Print Area   0   1    0   2    0   2    0   1   0   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
5     25 Copthall   3rd  Breakout Space   1   6    0   3    2   6    2   4   3   6   2   4   2   4   1   3   0   1
6     25 Copthall   3rd    Meeting Room   5  10    8  13    8  19    6  16   6  15   5  12   6  12   6  15   4   8
7     25 Copthall   3rd      Print Area   0   0    0   0    0   1    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Edit: adding modulo to handle 12 am/pm

Comment: Thank you! this works but the problem is that now it puts 12pm last, but it needs to be after 11am.

Comment: @ArinaBelozerova Oh ok! I'm not familiar with the am/pm system. I added modulo to my answer to fix this!